# Disable Order Confirmation Email for particular customer group

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-email, customer-group, m2e

Is there a way to disable a Magento `Order Confirmation Email` for a particular **customer group** ?

I won't mind someone giving me a guide on how to create a custom module for this function.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope Not yet. Still working on the project

Comment: 1) See updated answer. 2) Can you give please post some details about your M2E settings? (multiple account, assigned customer groups etc.) It's an interessting question, that I can use too ... but it's not on top of my priority list ... so please add some info to make it reproducable.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to rewrite the `queueNewOrderEmail()` function from: `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` to your local codePool then put this:

```
public function queueNewOrderEmail($forceMode = false)
    {
        $storeId = $this->getStore()->getId();
        if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewOrderEmail($storeId)) {
            return $this;
        }

        // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
        $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
        $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);

        // Start store emulation process
        /** @var $appEmulation Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation */
        $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
        $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

        try {
            // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
            $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($this->getPayment())
                ->setIsSecureMode(true);
            $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
            $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            // Stop store emulation process
            $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
            throw $exception;
        }

        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

        // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
        if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
        } else {
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
        }

        /** @var $mailer Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer */
        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
        /** @var $emailInfo Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info */
        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
        $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
        if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
            // Add bcc to customer email
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
            }
        }
        $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

        // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy'
        if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'copy') {
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
                $emailInfo->addTo($email);
                $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
            }
        }

        // Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        ));

        /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
        $emailQueue = Mage::getModel('core/email_queue');
        $emailQueue->setEntityId($this->getId())
            ->setEntityType(self::ENTITY)
            ->setEventType(self::EMAIL_EVENT_NAME_NEW_ORDER)
            ->setIsForceCheck(!$forceMode);
        //The add
        $customerGroups = array(1, 3); //the customer group id's that you don't send Email
        $currentCustomerGroup = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
        if(!in_array($currentCustomerGroup, $customerGroups)) {
            $mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
            $this->setEmailSent(true);
        }

        $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'email_sent');

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your input. This didn’t work for me.

Comment: It should work, i tested it ! maybe you haven't rewrite correctly the model ! reference you to this: `http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a small extension like this:

> app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </my_module>
        </models>
        <events>
            <!-- onepage checkout -->
            <checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
                <observers>
                    <disable_new_order_email>
                        <class>my_module/observer</class>
                        <method>disableNewOrderEmail</method>
                    </disable_new_order_email>
                </observers>
            </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
            <!-- multishipping checkout -->
            <checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single>
                <observers>
                    <disable_new_order_email>
                        <class>my_module/observer</class>
                        <method>disableNewOrderEmail</method>
                    </disable_new_order_email>
                </observers>
            </checkout_type_multishipping_create_orders_single>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/My/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Observer
{
    public function disableNewOrderEmail(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $noEmail = array(0, 1, 2, 3); // your customer group IDs
        if (in_array($order->getCustomerGroupId(), $noEmail)) {
            $order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Reference to the related code:

> Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::saveOrder()

```
public function saveOrder()
{
    ...
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after',
            array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$this->getQuote()));
        ...
        if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
            try {
                $order->queueNewOrderEmail();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
    ...
}
```

---

**Edit:**

For M2E you can try to modify/rewrite

- `Ess_M2ePro_Model_Amazon_Order`
- `Ess_M2ePro_Model_Ebay_Order`

Try this:

```
public function afterCreateMagentoOrder()
{
    if ($this->getAmazonAccount()->isMagentoOrdersCustomerNewNotifyWhenOrderCreated()) {
        $order = $this->getParentObject()->getMagentoOrder();
        $noEmail = array(0, 1, 2, 3); // your customer group IDs
        if (in_array($order->getCustomerGroupId(), $noEmail)) {
            if (method_exists($order, 'queueNewOrderEmail')) {
                $order->queueNewOrderEmail(false);
            } else {
                $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
            }
        }
    }

    if ($this->isFulfilledByAmazon() && !$this->getAmazonAccount()->isMagentoOrdersFbaStockEnabled()) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('m2epro_amazon_fba_magento_order_place_after', array(
            'magento_order' => $this->getParentObject()->getMagentoOrder()
        ));
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2:**

In M2Es account configuration you have to set a customer group that is used for eBay/Amazon order creation. So, for one account the customer group is always the same!

If you have more the one account you can set differnt groups *(like amazon-uk, amazon-it)* and use the code from above. *(I haven't tested it yet, but i can do it next week)*

Comment: Thanks for your input. This wouldn’t work for me because the orders in questions are Amazon orders that are been generated my M2E, not the normal Magento orders. Thanks

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for getting back in touch.

Here is my setup. 

I have two customer groups named Amazon Customers and EBay Customer with this corresponding Group Ids 7 & 8.

So all orders that’s comes through any of the Amazon Store fronts (like amazon-uk, amazon-it) goes into the Amazon Customers with Group id 7 likewise the Ebay Orders.

So I am trying to stop Magento from sending Order Confirmation emails or any email at all to all the customers that belongs to the Amazon Customers with Group id 7.

Thanks